# Undefined is not a function Intern Js

Tags: intern

Hi friends I have just setup the Intern Js, when i trying to run  the functional test it is giving me below mentioned error:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Transformation error; return original code
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
ReferenceError: __cov_VQFOzwnac8hdvD0fpGS2FQ is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous>  </Users/rmiglani/Downloads/intern-tutorial-master/internjs/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/node_modules/escodegen/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-node.js:5:0>
  at Module._compile  <module.js:460:26>
  at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js]  <internjs/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:107:24>
  at Module.load  <module.js:355:32>
  at Function.Module._load  <module.js:310:12>
  at Module.require  <module.js:365:17>
  at require  <module.js:384:17>
  at Object.load  <internjs/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/node.ts:56:11>
  at injectPlugin  <internjs/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:711:6>
  at injectModule  <internjs/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:733:3>
```

Please help me to resolve this, please let me know where i have could have done the mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Intern is trying to map the coverage reports from Istanbul back to the source code, but is failing to do so. It is hard to diagnose your exact problem without seeing your Intern config file, but my guess is you are missing an [`excludeInstrumentation`](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-excludeInstrumentation) option. If that option is in fact missing from your config, I recommend using the value provided in the [example config](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/tests/example.intern.js).